# Design QA: Tools to support?

Tags: app, testing, quality-assurance

I'm looking for a tool where I would be able to almost 'inspect' the elements of an app build to make sure they match the design I created.

So currently my Devs will create a build using [Test Flight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/) and then I review it, but if they have used a slightly wrong font-weight or spacing then I have to do it by eye. Is there any tool that would allow me to see the code or the breakdown of elements on the app?

Comment: None that come to mind, I think if such a tool existed, it would have to be provided by Apple/Google themselves, since it would need a lot of permissions to deconstruct other apps. Maybe it would help you if you could look into the frontend file (UI and also colors, fonts etc.) if that is possible. There you would see  specific colors & fonts used (it's not really so hard to read).

Answer (score 1):

I think if you can create the design system for the app or share the figma, xd or axure design file with them. They can prefer the style code and add to the thier code.

Comment: While this is indeed a good way I think the OP asked about checking after the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

using test flight means you are building for apple so your app is build on Xcode.
In Xcode you need to ask your devs to enable the Accessibility Inspector.From there on you can make a build and debug it your self.

The accessibility inspector should be able to tell you exactly where fonts, colors etc is located in code, so you can inspect them first hand.

Answer (score 0):

[Wisiwig](https://www.wisiwig.co/) allows you to inspect, edit, and share designs and CSS/JSON with their Chrome extension. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Welcome to [ux.se]! The question is about a native mobile app - would it work for those kind of apps?

Answer (score 0):

I can't advise you on a specific tool, because the tool depends on the project and requires consistency and management not only from your side but also from the side of the developers.

As an example, after you have created your design system, you give it to developers. I am specifically talking about the design system and not about the usual Mock-ups, as it is the basis.

So, the developers transfer your design to themselves in the form of code. They should have their own **Storybook or system** where all the components are. In fact, this is the same design system as you.

You must have access to this storybook, where you can make your visual QA